# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using entity framework in asp.net mvc3 and when i try to add new record to a table i get this error. Here is my code

```
namespace CvGenerator.Models
{
    public class LogInEntities:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet LogIn { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<LogIn>().ToTable("LogInData");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

}
```

Model controller:

```
public class LogIn
{
    public int LogInId { get; set; }
    public string NameAndSurname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LogIn> LogInCol { get; set; }
}
```

Method which i call using ajax to record data:

```
public void LogIn(string email,string nameAndSurname)
{
    LogInEntities logIndb = new LogInEntities();
    LogIn logIn = new LogIn();

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        logIn.Email = email;
        logIn.NameAndSurname = nameAndSurname;
        ***logIndb.LogIn.Add(logIn);***
        logIndb.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

on marked row i get the exeption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try DbSet<Login> Logins instead

Answer (score 0):

Have a look i just made little change in your `LogIn`  property and constructor of `LogInEntities`.

Hope you won't get excepion at mentioned line now.

```
namespace CvGenerator.Models
{
    public class LogInEntities:DbContext
    {
        List<DbSet> lgn;
        public LogInEntities()
        {
             lgn = new List<DbSet>();
        }
        public List<DbSet> LogIn { get{return lgn;} set{lgn=value;} }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<LogIn>().ToTable("LogInData");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

}
```

Model controller:

```
public class LogIn
{
    public int LogInId { get; set; }
    public string NameAndSurname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LogIn> LogInCol { get; set; }
}
```

Method which i call using ajax to record data:

```
public void LogIn(string email,string nameAndSurname)
{
    LogInEntities logIndb = new LogInEntities();
    LogIn logIn = new LogIn();

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        logIn.Email = email;
        logIn.NameAndSurname = nameAndSurname;
        ***logIndb.LogIn.Add(logIn);***
        logIndb.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

on marked row i get the exeption